# How to map angle brackets in Windows gVim?

Tags: vim

I code a lot of HTML and I'd like to map `CTRL+>` to `&gt;` and `CTRL+<` to `&lt;` respectively, to make it easier when typing out lots of text featuring those symbols.

After checking the Vim manual, I tried using `imap <C->> &gt;`, `imap <C-\>> &gt;` and even `imap <C-S-.> &gt;` but so far I've had no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

All the `<C-X>` type combinations are for "Ctrl+X", you need:

```
:imap < &lt;
:imap > &gt;
```

As an alternative, you could also consider using `:ab`:

```
:iab < &lt;
:iab > &gt;
```

Then you type <kbd><</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> and you'll get `&lt;`.  This allows you to type:

```
<a href
```

and get:

```
<a href
```

or type:

```
X < Y
```

and get:

```
X &lt; Y
```

Hope that helps, for more information, see:

```
:help :imap
:help :abbreviations
```

Answer (score 1):

As a compromise, I've found I can do `imap <M-.> &gt;` and `imap <M-,> &lt;`, which allows me to use `ALT+.` to type `&gt;` and `ALT+,` to type `&lt;` respectively. I suspect that not all CTRL+<key> combinations are supported.

Comment: The easy way to check whether a CTRL+<key> can be mapped is to go into insert mode and type <C-V><C-(key)><ESC>.  If you type Ctrl-V, Ctrl-., nothing will be entered, but if you type Ctrl-V Ctrl-D, you'll get ^D.